# SQL Alternative to Like to return exact matches (ie.?

Tags: sql, match

I need this to return an exact match while still being able to use the wild card.

So when searching for 'carb' i want to return a value such as 'Racing Carb' 
but i do not want to return a value such as 'Racing Carburetor'

This is what I have now...

```
SELECT  I.SKU, I.[Description]
FROM    Inventory AS I  
INNER JOIN MisspelledWords AS M
ON I.[Description] like   '%' + M.[Word] + '%'
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but have you tried NOT LIKE instead of LIKE?  Does that give you what you want?

Comment: This query matches any part of a string containing the value ie 'carburetor' will be returned with a 'carb'

Comment: search. But i only want to get results with the exact word 'carb'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ON I.[Description] like '%[^a-z]' + M.[Word] + '[^a-z]%'
```

**Update**

```
declare @word varchar(100)
set @word = 'carb' 

select 1 
where  'Racing Carburetor' like '%[^a-z]' + @word + '[^a-z]%'
```

Returns nothing, which means that 'Racing Carburator' isn't getting selected.

**Update 2**

```
declare @searchWord varchar(100), @tableWord varchar(100)
select @searchWord = 'carburetor' 
,@tableWord = 'Racing Carburetor'

select 1 
where  @tableWord like '%[^a-z]' + @searchWord + '[^a-z]%'
or @tableWord like @searchWord + '[^a-z]%'
or @tableWord like '%[^a-z]' + @searchWord
```

This one deals with marginal cases.

Comment: Thank you, but I alraedy tried this and it returns the same results

Comment: Can u update the query to handle words congaing numbers too . for example this will still return 1 when query is select 1 where  'Racing Carb9 uretor' like '%[^a-z]' + @word + '[^a-z]%' . But actually it shouldn't as our searchword is just "carb"

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about mysql or ms-sql, but you can use regexp_like function in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

try

`(field like '%carb' or field like '%carb %')`

This will match `racing carb` and `carb for racing` but not `racing carburator` or `carburator for racing`.